# XNA sprite intersection test based on alphas?

Tags: xna, transparency, intersection, alpha

Is it possible to test intersections with 2 sprites in XNA using the sprites' alpha channels to determine if alpha > 0 with an intersection there is a collision but if alpha is 0 even if there is an intersection there's no collision.

I know j2me supports it at least...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [2D Per-Pixel Collision](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel) sample.

Comment: The tutorial was moved [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel).
A good overview can also be found [here](http://www.andrewshough.com/development/per-pixel-collision-detection-in-2d-games/)